# Manipulating data in text file using powershell commands

Tags: powershell

I am new to PowerShell. I'd like to add double quotation and OR, e.g.,"word" OR, for each line in a text file and output the results in a new file. I got this so far: `%{" "$_ " OR "}` but of course it's giving me the following error: `Unexpected token`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nested double quotes must be escaped (escape character in PowerShell is the backtick):

```
% { "`"$_`" OR" }
```

Comment: Thank you. Now how do you get rid of the white space at the end of each line?.

Comment: [Trim](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trim%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) it.

Comment: The actual file has white space at the end of each string, how do you get ride of it using PowerShell?. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I already told you. For further advice please post a new question. Make sure you include sample input and output.

Comment: I got it! Thanks again.